# Why does Google still use SHA-1 for securing API keys if its been compromised?

Tags: hash, google

If you read [Google's best practices for use account](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/12-best-practices-for-user-account) you'd see them warning against using SHA-1. They have even [purposefully cracked it in 2017](https://www.theverge.com/2017/2/23/14712118/google-sha1-collision-broken-web-encryption-shattered).

If that's the case, then why when you restrict google cloud API keys for android apps, you use a SHA-1 fingerprint of your android app? Seeing as how its trivial to fake a package name (the other required detail to identify your app) you're only left with a security method thats been already cracked.

Why would Google secure such an important thing as an API key with a hashing algorithm that they warn against?

I have searched an answer for this on the web, and while there are some answers that deal with this topic, none specifically deals with the dissonance google has shown.

Answer (score 5):

Im summary: SHA-1 has various use cases and while some are considered broken others are not.

You are mixing apples and oranges:

> ... them warning against using SHA-1.

They advice against SHA-1 to be used as hash in storing passwords. But this is not specific to SHA-1, it is even a bad idea to use SHA-2 for storing passwords. See also [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords).

> They have even purposefully cracked it in 2017.

They have shown a collision attack. This is not "cracked" in the general sense but it shows a specific weakness and affects only use cases where collision attacks can be a problem.

> ... then why when you restrict google cloud API keys for android apps, you use a SHA-1 fingerprint of your android app?  Seeing as how its trivial to fake a package name (the other required detail to identify your app) you're only left with a security method thats been already cracked.

If you want to reuse an API key which belongs to the app of another party then you have to mount a pre-image attack and not a collision attack. Pre-image attacks against SHA-1 are not feasible so far.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer and yet another reminder of the fundamental property of cryptography: Crypto is hard.